# Changing the speed limits when asking for Route or Route Matrix in MapQuest / OpenStreetMap?

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, mapquest

I am looking into MapQuest API for OpenStreetMap and it seems to be a nice little service =)

I have been looking a little bit for a way to change/set the speed of the roads before asking for a Route or Route Matrix. At some times you know that there is a blizzard or something else that slows down traffic. At those times, you would want to decrease the speed of certain types of roads.

So, is there a way to do this in the HTTP request, either for MapQuest or some other service that uses OpenStreetMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [MapQuest Open Directions Service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/) does not support a change to the speed associated with a route as an input parameter.  The Open Directions Service also does not support the route matrix functionality.  If you have any other questions about the [MapQuest Open Data and Services](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open), feel free to check out the [forums](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/forums) on the [MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com).

The [Licensed version](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products) (Community Edition) of the [MapQuest Directions Web Service](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/) does offer [route matrix](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/#matrix) functionality, but it does not allow for manipulation of road speed limit data. I know it's a bit confusing, but the licensed version of MapQuest APIs and Web Services use commercial data, rather than freely-available data from OpenStreetMap.

Jonathan

Comment: Thx for the answer, then I know. Are you by any chance working for MapQuest? I think that MapQuest, at least for the licensed version, would do good if they let ppl change the speed of the roads in their requests =)